# Splitting Credits and Debits on a Pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I've got the following query:

```
DECLARE @cols AS varchar(8000) = ''
DECLARE @selectcols AS varchar(8000) = ''
DECLARE @query AS varchar(8000) = ''

SELECT @cols = @cols + QUOTENAME(Type) + ',' FROM (select distinct [Type] from #temp) as tmp order by Type
SELECT @cols = LEFT(@cols, LEN(@cols) - 1) 

SELECT @selectcols = @selectcols + 'ISNULL(' + QUOTENAME(Type) + ',0) as ' + QUOTENAME(Type) +',' FROM (select distinct Type from #temp) as tmp order by Type
SELECT @selectcols = LEFT(@selectcols, LEN(@selectcols) - 1) 

SET @query = 
'
select 
    PostDate,
    Status,
    Account,
    ' + @selectcols + '
from
    #temp
    pivot
    (
      sum(Amount)
      for Type in (' + @cols + ')
    ) p
'

EXECUTE (@query)
```

It gives the following results:

[image]

What I'm needing to do however is for all the different Types, is show the Credits and Debits in different columns, i.e. Type 1 (Credits), Type 2 (Debits), Type 1 (Credits), Type 2 (Debits), etc.

I know I could do something similar to this:

```
CASE WHEN amount >= 0 THEN amount
     ELSE NULL
END AS debit ,
CASE WHEN amount < 0 THEN amount
     ELSE NULL
END AS credit
```

But I'm not sure how to incorporate it into the pivot. How could this be done?

Test Data

```
Create Table #temp
(
    Type varchar(50),
    Amount money,
    PostDate varchar(50),
    Status varchar(50),
    Account varchar(50)
)

insert into #temp
(
    Type,
    Amount,
    PostDate,
    Status,
    Account
)
select
    'Type 1',
    '296.60',   
    'September 2019',
    'Current',
    '6116'
union all
select
    'Type 1',   
    '-195.51',  
    'September 2019',   
    'Former',   
    '6116'
union all
select
    'Type 2',   
    '150.00',   
    'September 2019',   
    'Former',   
    '6113'
union all
select
    'Type 2',   
    '180.43',   
    'September 2019',   
    'Former',   
    '6113'
union all
select
    'Type 2',   
    '-1860.10', 
    'September 2019',   
    'Former',   
    '6113'
union all
select
    'Type 2',   
    '1644.11',  
    'September 2019',
    'Former',   
    '6113'
union all
select
    'Type 2',   
    '655.38',   
    'September 2019',   
    'Former',   
    '6113'
union all
select
    'Type 2',   
    '366.42',   
    'September 2019',   
    'Current',  
    '6113'
union all
select
    'Type 2',   
    '-403.92',  
    'September 2019',   
    'Former',   
    '6113'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see why you need dynamic SQL.  In this case, it looks like conditional aggregation:

```
select postdate, status, account,
       sum(case when type = 1 and amount > 0 then amount end) as type1_credit,
       sum(case when type = 1 and amount < 0 then amount end) as type1_debit,
       sum(case when type = 2 and amount > 0 then amount end) as type2_credit,
       sum(case when type = 2 and amount < 0 then amount end) as type2_debit
from #temp
group by postdate, status, account;
```

Of course, if you don't know the types in the data, then you can adapt the above to dynamic SQL.

Comment: Fair enough point Gordon, I don't know the Types, so thought there would be a cleaner way of doing the above through the pivot.